# Why compressed bytes is bigger than bytes?

Tags: c#, file

In below code, I noticed that `compressedBytes` value is 147, which is greater than `bytes` 100.

I thought `compressedBytes` should be less. Please suggest why?

```
byte[] compressedBytes;
        byte[] bytes = File.ReadAllBytes(filename); //byte[100]
        using (var outStream = new MemoryStream())
        {
            using (var archive = new ZipArchive(outStream, ZipArchiveMode.Create, true))
            {
                var fileInArchive = archive.CreateEntry("test.txt", CompressionLevel.Optimal);
                using (var entryStream = fileInArchive.Open())
                using (var fileToCompressStream = File.Open(filename, FileMode.Open))
                {
                    var X = fileToCompressStream.Length; //100
                    fileToCompressStream.CopyTo(entryStream);
                }
            }
            compressedBytes = outStream.ToArray(); //byte[147]
        }
```

Comment: What you're trying to compress is too small to achieve any benefit, and you have the overhead of the zip special characters, the zip entry, and the text you've added.

Comment: *In below code, I noticed that compressedBytes value is 147, which is greater than bytes 100. I thought compressedBytes should be less.* If compressing something always made it smaller, what's to stop you from compressing a zip file repeatedly until its size reaches 0???

Comment: Also keep in mind that there is no lossless compression algorithm that can compress every possible input. [It's simply not possible](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pigeonhole_principle).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Very very simplified, imagine that ZIP file works like this:

- It has an index where it says what filenames it contains and where we can find them
- It compresses each file by saying how many times each byte is repeated

So, if you have a file `layers.pic` that contains: 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 50 50 50 50 50 50 50 50 100 100 100 100 100 100 100 100 100 100 100 100 100 100 100 100, you could say instead say: "`layers.pic`, right after index, 8x0, 8x50, 16x100" and it would be shorter. But imagine if a file only has `0 17 39`; then the "compression" would actually be twice as long as the file (1x0 1x17 1x39), and you'd still need to waste additional space telling the index what its original name is and where to find it. Even if we decided compression is not worth it and stored the file as-is into the archive, we'd still increase the file size because we need to put something in the index.

(ZIP archive is a bit more complicated than this; but the basic principles are quite close - including the option to not compress if the entry would end up larger.)

EDIT: If you check out the [Wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zip_(file_format)), you can find out that each file entry has a header of at least 30 bytes plus file name size; the central index repeats that information again, in a bit expanded form; then there's the EOCD that is at least 20 bytes. Your file is named `test.txt` for 8 bytes, so just the metadata occupies at least (30+8) + (46+8) + 20 = 112 bytes already, without your compressed data itself (which are consequently taking up at most 35 bytes).